# Opening .apr file in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arcview-3

I have a bunch of old .apr files, just wondering if it is possible to open in ArcView 10.3.1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Click Customise
2. Go to Commands
3. Type ArcView

You'll see "Import from ArcView Project". Drag it to any menu or toolbar. You'll be able to import from both apr and odb files.